# recent and table_uiprefs not ok

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So, I've been trying to get phpMyAdmin to work without problem but I can't figure out what's the problem. It says that everyting is ok EXCEPT $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs']

config.inc.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Debian local configuration file
 *
 * This file overrides the settings made by phpMyAdmin interactive setup
 * utility.
 *
 * For example configuration see
 *   /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.sample.inc.php
 * or
 *   /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.manyhosts.inc.php
 *
 * NOTE: do not add security sensitive data to this file (like passwords)
 * unless you really know what you're doing. If you do, any user that can
 * run PHP or CGI on your webserver will be able to read them. If you still
 * want to do this, make sure to properly secure the access to this file
 * (also on the filesystem level).
 */

// Load secret generated on postinst
include('/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php');

// Load autoconf local config
include('/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php');

/**
 * Server(s) configuration
 */
$i = 0;
// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use $cfg['Servers'][0].
// You can disable a server config entry by setting host to ''.
$i++;

/**
 * Read configuration from dbconfig-common
 * You can regenerate it using: dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
 */
if (is_readable('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php')) {
    require('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php');
} else {
    error_log('phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php.'
        . ' Check group www-data has read access.');
}

/* Configure according to dbconfig-common if enabled */
if (!empty($dbname)) {
    /* Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    /* Server parameters */
    if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;

    if (!empty($dbport) || $dbserver != 'localhost') {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
    }
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    /* Select mysqli if your server has it */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    /* Optional: User for advanced features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
    /* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';

    /* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
     * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

    /* Advance to next server for rest of config */
    $i++;
}

/* Authentication type */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/* Optional: User for advanced features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/*  Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
 * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is it complaining about, what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Pekka웃 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Persistent recently used tables: Disabled
 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Persistent tables' UI preferences: Disabled

Comment: Have you clicked the "Documentation" link?

Comment: @Pekka웃 the documentation tells me to add $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent'; and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs'; which I have, I don't know why but when I import the .sql-file I see every table but when I reload it says "No tables found in database". It only occurs to my pma database.

Comment: I have the same problem, but after delete $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent'; and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs'; Phpmyadmin page never reports the error again. It's just in the main page, there's always a red error saying there are some functions deactivated.

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 Short answer, Add the config, add tables in database, logout of PMA and login again. See answer below.

Answer (score 7):

I just upgraded from PMA v3.5.4 to v4.0.5 and ran into the same issue

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

clicking on the link gave me a run down of what is not setup yet

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
> Persistent recently used tables: Disabled
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
> Persistent tables' UI preferences: Disabled

### Quick steps to setup advanced features:

Copied from the bottom of `http://SERVER/phpmyadmin/chk_rel.php`

- Create the needed tables with the examples/create_tables.sql. Documentation
- Create a pma user and give access to these tables. Documentation
- Enable advanced features in configuration file (config.inc.php), for example by starting from config.sample.inc.php. Documentation
- **Re-login to phpMyAdmin to load the updated configuration file.**

### Detailed:

**Step 1.** Add additional configuration into `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent']        = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
```

**Step 2.** Modify phpMyAdmin database using `phpMyAdmin/examples/create_tables.sql`. ***Renamed the table names of course!***

```sql
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma_recent`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_recent` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pma_table_uiprefs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_uiprefs` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `prefs` text NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

**Step 3.** Make sure to logout of PhpMyAdmin and re-login, refresh will not reload the config file.

and we are left with no more errors

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] ...   OK
Persistent recently used tables: Enabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] ...    OK
Persistent tables' UI preferences: Enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem::

Please see the documentation on how to update your column_info table. Documentation
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    OK

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ... not right
Persistent favorite tables: off

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] ...  not right
Managing Central list of columns: off

---

config.inc.php::

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';